# is "Wait for callback" pattern in AWS step functions the only way to perform async tasks? Can I use a webhook instead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, callback, webhooks, aws-step-functions

is "Wait for callback" pattern in AWS step functions the only way to perform asynchronous tasks?

Can I directly use a webhook instead where when a the webhook endpoint it can trigger the step function to continue with the flow?

Comment: How would the webhook know which flow to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wait for a Callback with the Task Token / .waitForTaskToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token) is the right feature of [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), but it does not provide a native webhook interface. You would need build that interface on top of this feature. While not webhooks, [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/integrating-aws-step-functions-callbacks-and-external-systems/) demonstrates using .waitForTaskToken with an external system.

I suspect this does not fit your needs, but for select AWS service API Actions, you can use the Run a Job / .sync service integration pattern. With this pattern, the asynchronous tracking and completion is managed for you. You can find [the list of Optimized Integrations that support .sync here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html).

Comment: Thank you, I was just watching a video on youtube (Serverless land channel) with you in it. :)